# Inner join not working with View in mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, inner-join

I am developing MVC application, where I am passing Inner join result from controller to view like below:

```
    public class CartController : Controller
{
    ApostilleUSEntities db = new ApostilleUSEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var query = db.tbl_cart
                        .Join(db.tbl_document_type,
                               cart => cart.document_type_id,
                               doc_type => doc_type.document_type_id,
                               (cart, doc_type) => new { Cart = cart,Doc_type = doc_type }
                        ).ToList();

        return View(query);
    }
}
```

and in view I display list like below:

```
@{
var index=1;
foreach (var i in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@index</td>
        <td>@i.country_id</td>

    </tr>
    index++;
}
```

}

which is giving me below error:
Cart does not exist in object

If I change inner join to simple join like this:

```
    public class CartController : Controller
{
    ApostilleUSEntities db = new ApostilleUSEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var query1 = db.tbl_cart.ToList();
        return View(query);
    }
}

@{
    var index=1;
    foreach (var i in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@index</td>
            <td>@i.country_id</td>

        </tr>
        index++;
    }
}
```

it works all fine.
Is Dynamic view not works with inner join?
Should I use Model for that?

Comment: What did you define your Model as in the view? Set it to `dynamic`, if you haven't already.

Comment: What should I do, if I want to get data from Doc_type in same foreach loop?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7t9j35, please check the latest code of the view

Comment: `@i.country_id` should now be `@i.Cart.country_id`

Comment: Suggestion not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the usage of Model property. You are returning two objects Cart and Doc_type but in the View you are iterating over Model properties which are again Cart and Doc_type.

You can try with @i.Cart.country_id

Another solution is that you can bind a strongly typed model with the view. You can return a strongly typed ViewModel like:

```
 var query = db.tbl_cart
                    .Join(db.tbl_document_type,
                           cart => cart.document_type_id,
                           doc_type => doc_type.document_type_id,
                           (cart, doc_type) => new 
CartModel { 
    CartProp1 = cart.Prop1,
    CartProp2 = cart.Prop2,
    CartProp3 = cart.Prop3,
    DocProp1 =  doc_type.Prop1, 
    DocProp2 = doc_type.Prop2
}
                    ).ToList();
```